# android-textview's height is not what I've set

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

This is my listview , it has 4 textviews inside each row . I need to make all textview's height the like each other . as you can see ,it doesn't and as you can see , two textview's doesn't have the same height .

I tried to manually set the height , but it doesn't work either. THis is my code :

```
                holder.dates.getLayoutParams().height=150;
            holder.dates.setLayoutParams(holder.dates.getLayoutParams());

            holder.emtiaz.getLayoutParams().height=150;
            holder.emtiaz.setLayoutParams(holder.emtiaz.getLayoutParams());

            holder.dustan.getLayoutParams().height=150;
            holder.dustan.setLayoutParams(holder.dustan.getLayoutParams());

            holder.numquestions.getLayoutParams().height=150;
            holder.numquestions.setLayoutParams(holder.numquestions.getLayoutParams());
```

the result :
[image]

two of them have 2 lines .

How can I make all textview's height like each other ?

Comment: If you're changing a view's dimension after it has been drawn, you should call `yourView.requestLayout()`

Answer (score 0):

Try and set the textview heights in the xml layout?

```
android:layout_height="150dp"
```

Comment: I don't want to change every row's height ,just the first row